# NoReverseMatch at / Django template rendering

Tags: django, django-models, error-handling, django-templates, django-urls

I have this problem and been stuck for few hours.

NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'hotovo' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hotovo/(?P[^/]+)$'].

urls:

`urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('hotovo/<jedlo_id>', views.hotovo, name='hotovo')
    ]`

views:

```
def hotovo(request, jedlo_id):
jedlo = VyberJedla.objects.get(pk=jedlo_id)
jedlo.vybrane = True
jedlo.save()

return redirect('')
```

template:

```html
<body>

  <h1>Veber si z jedal:</h1>
  {% block content%}
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  {% for zoznam in zoznam%}
    {%if zoznam.vybrane%}
      <h1><a href="{% url 'hotovo' jedlo.id%}" class="hotovo"> {{zoznam.nazov_jedla}}</a><input type="checkbox" name="cekbox"></h1>
    {%else%}
      <h1><a href="{% url 'hotovo' jedlo.id%}" class="este_nie"> {{zoznam.nazov_jedla}}</a><input type="checkbox" name="cekbox"></h1>
    {%endif%}
  {%endfor%}
</div>
  {%endblock%}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to redirect to an empty path you need to change this

from

```
return redirect (' ')
```

To

```
return redirect ('/')
```

ALSO 
You need to render and pass jedelo object in your template which i didn't see here.

```
def hotovo(request, jedlo_id):
  jedlo=
  VyberJedla.objects.get(pk=jedlo_id)
  jedlo.vybrane = True
  jedlo.save()

  return render(request,'your_template',{'jedlo':jedlo})
```

EDIT : In your template you iterating the objects with loop variable `zoznam` so instead of `jedlo.id` use `zoznam.id`

```
  <h1><a href="{% url 'hotovo' zoznam.id 
%}" class="hotovo">
```

Make sure `zoznam.id` must be the same `VyberJedla` model object.

Comment: Can you share your full template

Comment: @PohodePES please attach this in your question

Comment: @PohodePES please  check the answer